# passing parameter to parsing of imported file

Tags: xslt, import, apply-templates

In parsing a WSDL, I come across many `wsdl:import` and `xsd:import` elements. I would like to parse the imports and pass the `@location` or `@schemaLocation` to the parser.

The intent is to have the file list grow when an imported file imports a file for example `filea.wsdl;filez.xsd;filev.xsd`. This way I can eliminate a previously imported file.

I would think something along along these lines:

```
<xsl:param name="file-list"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="file-list"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wsdl:import">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@location)">
        <xsl:with-param name="file-list" select="concat($file-list, ';', @location)`"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic idea seems to be fine. You just need to pass the the `file-list` parameter along when applying templates, so:

1. add a `<xsl:with-param name="file-list" value="$file-list"/>` to the `xsl:apply-templates` in your first template to actually pass the parameter, and
2. add a `<xsl:param name="file-list"/>` to your second template to introduce the parameter there.